# How to convert a temp folder( .tmp ) to a binary file ( .bin) in Linux

Tags: linux

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQQ3L.png)i.stack.imgur.com/*emphasized text*8kFIB.png

I want to convert the folder into a binary file(.bin),I tried  to write a shell file, but it not generate the correct binary file,I do not know how to solve it,maybe my solution is wrong.Someone tells me that I can use the command zip,I can not agree....C

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by binary file? Or by shell file?

Comment: What do you mean by "folder"?  Usually, that word is used in place of "directory", but how can you convert a directory into a regular file?  Are you wanting to create an archive of some sort (eg, `tar`, or `cpio`).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: The term "binary file" doesn't refer to a particular format, just to anything that's not human-readable (which would be a "text file"). Without knowing what format "the correct binary file" should be in, we have no way to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your remark about `zip`, it seems you are trying to make an archive.  One simple way to create an archive of a directory is with `tar`:

```
tar -zcf foo.tgz /path/to/foo
```

Note that this will create a file named `foo.tgz` rather than `*.bin`, but .... you don't really want to use the `bin` suffix for a tarball.

Comment: thank you very much，I think I should learn and practice linux better